# PHP - How to only post checked checkboxes in a loop?

Tags: php, post, mysqli, checkbox, while-loop

I am working on a project that signs up students to specific classes("french", "math",...). The student id is already selected. True a while loop i display my classes out of my database with a checkbox in front of each class. I only wanna post te checked checkboxes in a form that will send it to a php file thats puts the student and his selected classes into the database. But i cant seem to solve how i only post the checked checkboxes because of the difficulty with the while loop. I hope someone can help me. Already thanks!

Comment: can you show your code

Comment: Have you actually tried anything? HTML checkboxes _already_ only post the checked boxes by default.

Comment: Yes i have tried already. But because its a while loop the name of the input is always the same. So i tried to put the value on an arrays but then its sends all the classes. (I cant share my code i'am on mobile atm)

Comment: @michaldb For the name, add `[]` to the end of the name. This will allow it to submit all values that are checked as an array. For example, if the name of the field is `current_name`, change it to `current_name[]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would probably be to alter your HTML to POST the classes as an array instead of individual form elements.

```
<checkbox name="classes[]" value="CLASS_ID_1">
<checkbox name="classes[]" value="CLASS_ID_2">
<checkbox name="classes[]" value="CLASS_ID_3">
<checkbox name="classes[]" value="CLASS_ID_4">
```

Then, the PHP side of this is very easy. Only the checked checkbox values will appear on the processing page.

So, let's say that someone checks `CLASS_ID_1`, `CLASS_ID_3` and `CLASS_ID_4`;

```
print_r($_POST['classes']);
```

The above code should return;

```
array (
    "CLASS_ID_1",
    "CLASS_ID_3",
    "CLASS_ID_4"
)
```

So, essentially, it is an array of checked values. This means you do not need the class name or any additional information or loops to process the data.